# fetching data from the XML request and response

Tags: xml, splunk

I have xml data request and response in the splunk coming as below

**request**
3/11/21
8:07:36.967 PM
[3/12/21 1:07:36:967 UTC] 00001e46 LogMessageHan 3   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="fo">soapenv:BodyEWS123DDA345DDA1SxxxNrrr000</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

**response**
[3/11/21 7:13:59:061 UTC] 00001e0d LogMessageHan 3   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="fd"">SOAP-ENV:Body<NewTransferReply xmlns=fo.xsd">001Failure  OLAR500P ERROR CODE: 999  FILE IS CLOSED</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

now my requirement is to fetch all the transactions which are failing with error OLAR500P ERROR CODE: 999  FILE IS CLOSED where rrr

Comment: I need all transactions where <PaymentToken>rrr</PaymentToken>

Comment: is there any help

Comment: Did you solve this?  I only just noticed it.  It's actually not that hard - especially if you have a way to match up the request and response.  What do you have to match up the request and response?